# Data posted via form hangs application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have simple controller method like this:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add(InputModel input, OtherInputModel[] input2)
{
    (...)
}
```

Which receives data from this form below, but the problem is that when that simple endpoint
receives an `OtherInputModel[]` then it hangs up after clicking "Submit"

There's no error or anything at all - it's just stuck trying to enter that controller method, even if I'm not attaching images.

Changing `OtherInputModel[]` to `string[]` "solves" it, so it's still possile to access that method, but I want to send complex model []

```
<form asp-action="Add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Title</label>
        <input name="input.Title" class="form-control" value="@Model.Title" />
        <span class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Body</label>
        <input name="input.Body" class="form-control" value="@Model.Body" />
        <span class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <p>Upload one image ("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "bmp") using this form:</p>
            <input type="file" name="input.Image" />
        </div>
    </div>

    // here's probably the problem

    @for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label"></label>
            <input name="input2[].Text" class="form-control" />
            <span class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <p>Upload one image ("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "bmp") using this form:</p>
                <input type="file" name="input2[].Image" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="button" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Here are my models:

```
public class InputModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
}

public class OtherInputModel
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
}
```

I also tried using indexes in my form like that

```
<input name="input2[@i].Text" class="form-control" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a silly bug in ASP.NET Core 2.2. There is nothing to do with front-end, it is connected to that fact an action expects an array of complex objects containing `IFormFile` and model binding goes into inifinite loop (but it works fine in ASP.Core 2.1)

Here is and [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4802) on github regarding this bug. It's already closed an looks like the bug is fixed for ASP.NET Core 3.

However there are some workarounds suggested.

1.
 Put hidden input with `objectName.Index` name and value of index

```
<input type="hidden" name="otherinput.Index" value="0" />
<input type="file" name="otherinput[0].Image" />
```

Works fine, but if someone does request without `otherinput.Index` input (via postman or by removing `input` before submit) application will hang as it does without this workaround. So it's very fragile and unacceptable I'd say.

2.
 Wrap `IFormFile` into a class

```
public class OtherInputModel
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }

    public FileHolder Holder { get; set; }
}

public class FileHolder
{
    public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
}
```

And markup

```
<input name="otherinput[0].Text" class="form-control" value="create btn" />
<!-- second line won't work by itself, first line with Text or Body property is required -->
<input type="file" name="otherinput[0].Holder.Image" />
```

Works fine but folks say about possible memory leaks described in this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4564).

Comment: What?? I did both - used parameter name and used index. Anyway that's not the problem because if at the worst my parameter would be null, not the the hanged up application.

Comment: @tezzly Compare this `<input name="OtherInputModel[@i].Text" class="form-control" />` in your question to my answer

Comment: Ops, I'm sorry, I failed while rewriting my code to SO. I'm using parameter name and I even tried with indexes but the thing is that app just hangs up (request is trying to be sent in browser and app doesnt even hit breakpoint at methods opening ``{`` - no error, no anything.) If ``name`` was wrong then my param would be ``null`` but app would work "fine"

Comment: Not sure what happens with your app, but I tested this code and all values are binded fine. Have you tried it in different browsers?